# Data result should appear on one column

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am a self learner in SQL; I have created this code:

```
SELECT T0.[CardName], T0.[DocDate], T0.[DocDueDate], T2.[U_ExpDelDate], T0.[DocStatus], T1.[SlpName], 
CASE
WHEN DATEDIFF(day,DocDueDate,T2.[U_ExpDelDate]) <= 0 THEN 'Delivered'
WHEN DATEDIFF(day,DocDueDate,T2.[U_ExpDelDate]) >= 0 THEN 'Please Check'
ELSE NULL END AS 'Status',
DATEDIFF(day,DocDueDate,T2.[U_ExpDelDate]) AS 'Age'
FROM OPOR T0  INNER JOIN OSLP T1 ON T0.[SlpCode] = T1.[SlpCode] INNER JOIN POR1 T2 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T2.[DocEntry]

WHERE T0.[DocStatus] ='O' and T2.[U_ExpDelDate] is not null
```

I am getting the right result, but now I wanted Join the result `Delivered and Please Check` in `Age column`.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: By `JOIN` do you mean to concatenate? Just use `+` sign instead `,` and cast the values to string.

Comment: Or do you want to use the column AGE for calculating the column STATUS instead of writing the same formula 3 times?

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating strings in sql server is done by either using the [`+`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx) operator or the [`CONCAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) method.

Try this:

```
SELECT T0.[CardName], T0.[DocDate], T0.[DocDueDate], T2.[U_ExpDelDate], T0.[DocStatus], T1.[SlpName], 
CASE
WHEN DATEDIFF(day,DocDueDate,T2.[U_ExpDelDate]) <= 0 THEN 'Delivered '
WHEN DATEDIFF(day,DocDueDate,T2.[U_ExpDelDate]) > 0 THEN 'Please Check ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(day,DocDueDate,T2.[U_ExpDelDate]) as varchar)
END AS 'Age'
FROM OPOR T0  INNER JOIN OSLP T1 ON T0.[SlpCode] = T1.[SlpCode] INNER JOIN POR1 T2 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T2.[DocEntry]

WHERE T0.[DocStatus] ='O' and T2.[U_ExpDelDate] is not null
```

I've removed the `else` part since it's never going there, the `datediff` function will  either return a value that is less than or equal to 0 or more than 0.

Comment: Thanks you for the help. But it is showing (eg under Age column, "Delivered 0").

Comment: what is the difference, in days, between `DocDueDate` and `T2.[U_ExpDelDate]`? according to your comment, it should be 0...

Comment: Actually im quarrying SAP b1 database. Docduedate is the due date of the document you created and the ExpDelDate is the date of the expexted delivery date. In one column let say under AGE it will show delivered,please check or the number days left.

Comment: so if it's already delivered you don't want to see the number, but if it's not you want to see `Please Check <number of days>`?

Comment: yeah that' what i want to see. if that is possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks for sharing your codes. I will make modification from this on. What is the code you use again?

Comment: I don't understand your question.